# In eloquent fetching data in fieldname=>fieldvalue keys

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

In laravel 5.8 making request

```
        $searchResultsArray = SearchResult
            ::getBySourceId($next_sourceId['source_id'])
            ->select( 'field', 'value' )
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
```

I got resulting rows like :

```
$searchResultsArray::Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field] => Id
            [value] => 302530
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [field] => Domain
            [value] => site.com
        )
```

If there is a way to get 
  array of fieldname=>fieldvalue keys, like

```
Id => 302530 
Domain=> site.com
```

without additive foreach block in my code?

If yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. Eloquent always returns collections. You could modify the collection first with `mapWithKeys()` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-mapwithkeys) and then convert it to an array.

Try something like this:

```
$searchResultsArray = SearchResult
    ::getBySourceId($next_sourceId['source_id'])
    ->select( 'field', 'value' )
    ->get()
    ->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
        return [$item['field'] => $item['value']];
    })
    ->all();
```